# Run many users login at same time, always passed half and fail half in the controller

Tags: php, loadrunner

I setup a scenario in loadrunner controller to setup one group with 10 users login at same time, setup parameters with username as 10 usernames, setup parameters run the "next row" with "Unique".

1. if start 10 Vusers simultaneously till run completion. I got 5 users passes, 5 users failed.
2. if start 8 Vusers simultaneously till run completion. I got 4 users passes, 4 users failed.
3. if start 6 Vusers simultaneously till run completion. I got 3 users passes, 3 users failed.

Anyone know why that happens? My testcase just needs to run 10 users login at same time.

Comment: Can you add your code for some context to the question?

Comment: Maybe you are starting 2 users simultaneously each time and the server cannot handle it.

Comment: This cant be decided without knowing the exact error, this couldnt be the problem of parameter as if that could be the issue that would have failed at the starting of execution itself. It would be helpful to answer ur question if you could provide us with exact error message

Answer (score 0):

Can you please let us know the error which you are getting in output window.

looks like in sufficient parameters related to user name, did you select the password as same line as username.

Answer (score 0):

Real users do not engage in simultaneous synchronized behavior.   They may engage in a common activity in the same time window or they may have a coincident operation in the same section of code at the same time, but true synchronized simultaneity requires an automated agent and a clock tick.

Why don't you consider ramping up your users rather than starting them all at once and then ramping them down after your test window under load?